# Deploy independent EJB in WebLogic 12c

Tags: java, web-services, deployment, ejb, weblogic

I want to deploy a EJB module that i develop in Netbeans. The EJB contains web services using JAX WS library and Stateless Session Beans... The Session Bean class use a remote interface that is in another JavaApplication Project and in the same JavaApplication project has other classes used as library. The EJB use a datasource created in netbeans to connect with SQL SERVER and all work fine!... I read the documentation of weblogic 12c to deploy a independent EJB with webservices and connections to a DataBase but don´t understand very well how deploy the EJB...

what steps I have to follow to deploy this EJB? how package the ejb to use a JavaApplication as library? How the EJB connect to the DataBase? web services could be used by the wsdl?